# Inserting data with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not looking for solution to any specific problem, but rather would theoretically need advice on how to handle previously unknown count of data (rows).
Let's say I have a form divided into 3 categories (material, montage, minor budgetary costs).
Each category can have any count of items and each item has an id, a name and a price.
How should I store these data in MySQL database? Is it possible store it only to one table?
Thank you for any suggestion and direction.

**Quotation with some ID**

```
*categ Material*
------------------------------
title           ID       Price
------------------------------

first item    | 123 | 1 195.00

second item   | 845 |   469.00

...

*categ Montage*

item          | 461 |   146.00

item number 2 | 821 |   654.00

third item    | 012 |   931.00

...

*categ MBC*

item          | 642 | 2 135.00

...
```

Comment: You can always store everything in a single table. Whether you want an efficient solution or not is a different matter altogether

Comment: I would like to store it in a single table and I will need to edit data later too. Sure I need the most efficient solution, but I don't know how to do it... What you would do in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand how [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) works. Try to normalize your data and from there you may know how much tables you need. It makes sense to have a table called **Materials**, but for the other forms, their usage are not understandable.

Answer (score 1):

A normalized solution, using category & item as in the problem statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

You can have many items for each category.  Each item row in the item table is "connected" to the category by the category_id.  Create statements courtesy of MySQL.

Comment: I would like to avoid creating large numbers of tables. What I should do? I have an idea to create 3 tables named material, montage, .... and then insert for any quotation ID itself items. Is it right way?

Comment: Avoiding large numbers of tables is absolutely the right thing to do. Consider the relationships between the entities represented by each table.  For example, the category table has a one-to-many relationship with the item table.  The relationship is established by the `category_id` field in item.  Apply this concept to your tables.

Comment: Thank you geoB, I'm going to try it but it will take me a long time.

Answer (score 1):

You can store these in one table with four data columns.  What you are calling different "tables" might be called "categories" or something.  An example table structure would look like:

```
create table items (
    ItemId int not null auto_increment,
    CategoryName varchar(255) not null,
    Title varchar(255),
    Id int,
    Price decimal(10, 2)
);
```

This is an example.  Depending on your needs, you might want to enforce that `CategoryName` only takes on the values you want.  The best way is to have a separate `Categories` table with a proper foreign key reference.  You could also implement this using enumerated types, a trigger that implements a `check constraint`, or just dispense with the check altogether.  Similarly, the data types are just guesses, and you might want other fields.

Comment: Thank you very much for some knowledge.